# Dual SPI master control

Tags: spi, microprocessor, gpio

I'm looking at a dual master spi interface, it needs to run at 20MHz which means push-pull for me. 
My main concern is the output current of microprocessors, I could easily exceed the absolute maximum current rating if a software engineer decided to set one output high and the other one low on the microprocessor if they were set up as push-pull.

Open drain isn't going to work because of the 20MHz requirement and the amount of capacitance I have on my GPIO's. So my question is what circuit do I use to select between two dual masters?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA4qKY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What changes which master is active?

Comment: Software , so I need a way to physically switch one master to high impedance while the other talks, I can do this with another GPIO if necessary.

Comment: If your two master devices already have a reasonably high-speed link between them, it might be easiest to only connect one to the slave, and add a protocol to allow the other master to indirectly talk to the slave via that link.

Comment: @jasonharper the software engineer put the kibosh on that idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 4-way unidirectional digital multiplexer would do the trick. You can use a 74244 to produce this function (74HCT244 for 5 V logic, 74LVC244 for 3.3 V). It contains two tristate 4-bit buffers (see below).

[image: 74244]

(Sorry, unable to draw a schematic at present.)

Each master can have a 4-bit channel. Each master's SCK, MOSI and /CS drive the 1A or 2A buffer inputs with MISO taken a 1Y or 2Y buffer output. The other side of the channel buffers are connected to your SPI slave. Don't forget to put a 10 K pull-up on the slave's /CS. The slave's SCK also needs a 10 K pull-up or pull-down to pull it to its idle state, depending on your SPI mode used.

Connect /1OE to a select signal and /2OE to the inverse of the select signal. You can then switch between the two masters using select.

Comment: The signals used to drive these multiplexers would also be very convenient for use in the deconfliction and lockup-detection code the OP will likely need to implement.

Answer (score 1):

The device to put between is called arbiter. Arbiter may work using various algorithms:

- who comes first (master #1 or master #2)
- round robin
- priority setting (e.g. #1 has higher priority)
- any other suitable to your needs.

You need to consider priority of request, ensure that both masters are served *in time*, and that there are no conflicts between masters and software/firmware of both are aware of the wait cycles.

Edit: I was implementing it in FPGA, and it is possible to instantiate logically separate hardware there. In your case you can connect pins together only in case you guarantee that only one set will be active at a time, another set will be high impedance. The design may also require pull-ups/downs (should be no problem) to ensure there's no hi-z if no device is active. However if one of masters locks, there should be a way for another master to detect it, and be able to reset locked master. This is not a trivial task. E.g. both masters should be able to write onto output wires, and also read them to see what is going on there, and have watchdog/timers implemented which would indicate lock condition. In addition there may be some separate interconnection between masters which indicate their state in relation to their SPI bus operation.

I recommend considering another piece of hardware which will be doing it. It will be cost and even probably risk in terms of reliability (more components -> less reliability), but if all devices will be configurable you will be able to update their firmware in order to solve logical bugs (and you will not be able to solve "physical" bugs as it will require hardware changes in the field which are way much costly).

Comment: I need a *hardware* solution, what if one of my processors locks up and then for what ever reason the other one turns on the GPIO while one is low? Is it ever a good idea to have two outputs on a microprocessor that are set to push pull tied together?

Answer (score 1):

I'd reconsider whether this is actually a problem – how much does adding series resistor at either end (typically: at the masters' MISOs, and at the slave's MOSI) "hurt" your signal speed if your input pin is correctly High-Z?

In case of an arbitration failure, a 100Ω resistor might be more than sufficient to limit the current to "healthy" levels.

Comment: I thought about that, but at 100Ω I still get 33mA which exceeds my current rating for the MCU if one output is high and the other low. Plus I might run the MCU's at different voltage levels